# Detecting whether UIButton is being pressed with a specific time interval

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I just want to know whether `UIButton` is being pressed or not with a specific time interval. (2 sec in my code)
With a 2 sec period, some value should be 1 if the button is pressed, 2 if not.

In order to check that, I made my code below.
But `unexpected` results is coming and I have no idea how I can fix it.
Help me!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var gameTimer: Timer!

@IBAction func btnClick(_ sender: Any) {
    if let button = sender as? UIButton {
        if (button.isSelected) {
            print(" Not Selected");
        } else {
            print(" Selected");
        }
    }
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    gameTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2, target: self, selector: #selector(btnClick(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Comment: What should happen after waiting the first 2 seconds? does the value that you want to change is to be 2? i.e what's the reseting point for this scenario?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to check If UIButton is Pressed or not, You should handle [TouchDown](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicontrolevents/1618230-touchdown) Handler and change button's state to pressed in touchDown hadnler.
You can track ToucUpInside  method to Change state of button to Not-pressed again.

For ex:

```
button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(BtnPressed(_:)), for: .touch​Down);

button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(BtnReleased(_:)), for: .touch​Up​Inside);


var buttonSelection:Bool = false

 func BtnPressed(_ sender: Any) 
 {
      button.selected = true

  }

 func BtnReleased(_ sender: Any) 
 {
      button.selected = false

  }
```

Now, You can use timer to check state of button as follow:

```
 gameTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2, target: self, selector: #selector(IsButtonPressed()), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)



 func BtnPressed() 
 {

     if (button.isSelected) {
        print("Button is Pressed");
    } else {
        print("Not Pressed");
    }

  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. By using the addTarget syntax I solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var gameTimer: Timer!

    @IBAction func btnClick(_ sender: Any) {
        let button =  UIButton()
        if (button.isSelected) {
            print(" Not Selected");
        } else {
            print(" Selected");
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        gameTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2, target: self, selector: #selector(btnClick(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

BtnClick is the action of the button tapped, not supposed to be the method that the timer fires. Also, the isSelected is not relevant since it's something you need to set manually when the button is tapped. (It's a state of a button, not the action itself).

You need to do 2 changes:

1) In btnClick you need to do:

```
 btnClick.selected = true
```

2) The timer should fire other method, let's say func checkButtonState(), and in this method you need to check the button state like you did in btnClick

```
 func checkButtonState() {

    if (button.isSelected) {
        print(" Not Selected");
    } else {
        print(" Selected");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`sender as? UIButton` will not work since the sender in this case is your timer. If it was someone actually tapping the button, the button would be the sender. You should probably make your button a propterty and use this variable instead to check if `button.isSelected` is **true** or not.

/Knut

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding selector to Timer then the argument as default will go as Timer not as UIButton.

Below code won't execute:

```
if let button = sender as? UIButton
```

Instead take BOOL variable to check weather it is selected or Not selected

```
var buttonSelection:Bool = false

 func btnClick(_ sender: Any) 
 {
        if (buttonSelection == true) 
        {
           buttonSelection = false;
           print(" Not Selected");
        } else {
           buttonSelection = true;
           print(" Selected");
        }
  }
```

This will help to resolve your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Put this code in button action.

    @IBAction func btnClick(_ sender: Any) 
    {
        if let button = sender as? UIButton 
        {
            button.isSelected = true
        }

    }

    And change your timer selector

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        gameTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2, target: self, selector: #selector(timerSelector), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    timer selector will check button status.

    func timerSelector()
    {
        if (button.isSelected) {
                print(" Selected");
            } else {
                print("Not Selected");
            }
    }

if your button is pressed in 2 second than button.isseleced become true.
```